# Move element from one div to another, and remove duplicates that have same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sequelize.js, express-handlebars

I'm stuck with this piece of code:

From browser that is rendered:

```
<div id="prem_inner">
        <div id="Final doo                                                                                           ">
            <label class="font-size: 30px" id="Final doo                                                                                           komp"><i class="far fa-building" style="letter-spacing: 0.246em; font-size: 30px; color: #7313E9;"></i>Final doo                                                                                           </label>
            <label style="padding-left: 2em;" id="Kontrolor2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "><i class="fas fa-briefcase" style="letter-spacing: 0.246em; font-size: 30px; color: #7313E9;"></i>Kontrolor2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          </label>
        </div>
        <div id="Final doo                                                                                           ">
            <label class="font-size: 30px" id="Final doo                                                                                           komp"><i class="far fa-building" style="letter-spacing: 0.246em; font-size: 30px; color: #7313E9;"></i>Final doo                                                                                           </label>
            <label style="padding-left: 2em;" id="Kontrolor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "><i class="fas fa-briefcase" style="letter-spacing: 0.246em; font-size: 30px; color: #7313E9;"></i>Kontrolor                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           </label>
        </div>
        <div id="Final doo                                                                                           ">
            <label class="font-size: 30px" id="Final doo                                                                                           komp"><i class="far fa-building" style="letter-spacing: 0.246em; font-size: 30px; color: #7313E9;"></i>Final doo                                                                                           </label>
            <label style="padding-left: 2em;" id="Kontrolor3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "><i class="fas fa-briefcase" style="letter-spacing: 0.246em; font-size: 30px; color: #7313E9;"></i>Kontrolor3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Handlebars template(backend):

```
    <div id="prem_inner">
       {{#each gigs}}
        <div id="{{company_name}}">
            <label class="font-size: 30px" id="{{company_name}}komp"><i class="far fa-building" style="letter-spacing: 0.246em; font-size: 30px; color: #7313E9;"></i>{{company_name}}</label>
            <label style="padding-left: 2em;" id="{{job_title}}"><i class="fas fa-briefcase" style="letter-spacing: 0.246em; font-size: 30px; color: #7313E9;"></i>{{job_title}}</label>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
```

So.. My idea and client requirements are that it needs to be like sorted (if there is multiple company_name rendered with different job_title then it needs to be in the same column, if company_name is different than other first div then it needs to be inside another second column etc. )
When it is just rendered with handlebars(backend): [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsbgj.png)

So from that last img I want basically to remove any duplicates of label company_name except first one and then combine all divs with the same id eg. company_name to one column.
I'm free to explain to you more if I have missed something and I need to define, any id from code above is just an example, I'm free to change according to your recommendations.

I have used jQuery 3.4.1 but I'm also free to change it if it is needed, huh?
This is intended to remove all duplicates of the label with the same id (this is first part of my js on that page:

```
window.onload = function myFunction2() {
$('label[id$=komp]').each(function () {
    $('label[id="' + this.id + '"]:gt(0)').remove();

});
```

And this is the result: [With jQuery from above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pADtL.png)

Also, [there is a part of the structure of my DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWZIs.png) (Postgre, Sequelize)

Comment: Maybe consider do the sorting at the api before you return your data?

Comment: Like in the backend?

https://pastebin.com/1B54sbwq

That will be a massacre for me, Can you give me some tips on what to search on Google?

Comment: How is your data structure returned currently?

Comment: This is output of structure, i'm not sure, JSON? https://pastebin.com/LKmWdzup